# How get Woocomerce root URL to show shop?

Tags: woocommerce

I have a woocommerce site `https://example.com` but when enter this address I get a generic page from my hosting (hostgator) and to display the store I have to redirect to `https://example.com/shop/`

How can I get to the woocommerce store directly when I type `https://example.com`?

I have tried in permalinks and woocommerce > settings > products, but i can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

this answer my problem. It might help someone.

Go to Settings > Reading

on the section "Your homepage displays" select "A static page (select below)" and select your shop page.

After this step, your shop page’s URL slug will disappear automatically and the ‘.com’ version of your website link will lead straight to the shop page.